# Android - Video Gamification

Tags: android, video, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am looking to create a first-person game for the android platform, in which the environment is based upon the playback of a video that exists upon the device. I would like to control the speed of the video playback in order to mimic 'movement' through the game. The catch is that I would also like to be able to embed 3d objects into the player's view (avatars, checkpoints, etc...).

I was unable to find any examples of this type of 'game' through my research, and was hoping to get some assistance from the community to help me determine if this is indeed possible through the unity3d (or other suggested) engines, and if so to point me in some general directions of either tutorials/blogs/documentation that may help me piece this together.

I apologize for the vague nature of this post, however, I am a complete game development newcomer and am simply looking for general direction as opposed to specific code from the community, as I am unsure where to begin.

Background:
I have been able to create my own media player using android's media codec library, which is able to control video playback speeds within a certain bounds. However, my issue now is the ability to add 3d assets within the context of the video view.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

for 3d assets, you'll need to tap into opengl.

You'll most probably need to decode your video to an opengl texture which will be mapped on a 3d mesh in opengl.

Answer (score 0):

You can place video into mesh objects in Unity with this plugin:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032

Then you can place any 3D objects in the scene also.

(you can control playback with that plugin, but cannot access users videos directly, would need some other native plugin to do that, or load videos from outside server)